# How Can I add The Donation Amount To my Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[Donation Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNI8k.png) When i Click the donate Button i want to add that amount to my database but it always show 0 and never the amount i submitted. i just want to save the text amount that i typed inside the sql database

View

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/donate" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="elias.odeh@hotmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://yourdomain.com/notifypage.aspx">
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="{username or similar}">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
        <input type="text" name="amount">
        @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Amount, new { type = "text" })
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
        <br />
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    </form>
</div>
```

[DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdnRb.png)

Controller

```
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Id,Amount,User_Id")] MoneyDonation moneyDonation)
        {
                    moneyDonation.User_Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.moneydonation.Add(moneyDonation);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

Model

```
 public class MoneyDonation
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public string User_Id { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Have you ensured that the amount is being correctly bound to the `moneyDonation` model in your conroller before you add it to the db?

Comment: Yes Indeed it is correctly bounded

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpPost

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Id,Amount,User_Id")] MoneyDonation moneyDonation)
```